# Applying longest space between two words not working

Tags: shell, awk

I was trying to find the longest empty space between two words in a file and then apply that longest space to every empty space of each stanza. There are only spaces, no tabs. My file contains the below:

```
$ cat file1
firstCol     secondCol
blablablablablaetcetc    secondCol
test123                    12231blablablabla
test123         againtest123testbla
blablatest            againblabla
```

Here is what I have tried however that doesn't work.

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{print $0}' file1
```

Expected output

```
firstCol                    secondCol
blablablablablaetcetc                    secondCol
test123                    12231blablablabla
test123                    againtest123testbla
blablatest                    againblabla
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. I hope this is what you are looking for :)

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  match($0,/ +/)
  cs=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  max=(max>cs?max:cs)
  next
}
FNR==1{
  OFS=max
}
{
  print $1,$2
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows for above.

```
firstCol                    secondCol
blablablablablaetcetc                    secondCol
test123                    12231blablablabla
test123                    againtest123testbla
blablatest                    againblabla
```

Comment: You may wish to add `expand` to the process to make sure that the 'spaces' are uniformly spaces and not tabs and spaces...

Comment: @dawg, yeah this had been discussed yesterday, OP mentioned that there are no tabs and only spaces present, not sure commented got deleted here :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single pass `awk`:

```sh
awk '{r[FNR] = $0} match($0, /[[:blank:]]+/) && RLENGTH > max {max = RLENGTH; sp = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)} END {for (i=1; i in r; ++i) {sub(/[[:blank:]]+/, sp, r[i]); print r[i]}}' file1

firstCol                    secondCol
blablablablablaetcetc                    secondCol
test123                    12231blablablabla
test123                    againtest123testbla
blablatest                    againblabla
```

Readable form:

```sh
awk '{
   r[FNR] = $0
}
match($0, /[[:blank:]]+/) && RLENGTH > max {
   max = RLENGTH
   sp = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
END {
   for (i=1; i in r; ++i) {
      sub(/[[:blank:]]+/, sp, r[i])
      print r[i]
   }
}' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{match($0, /[ \t]+/, a);\
             if(max<length(a[0]))\
                 max=length(b=a[0])\
            }\
      NR!=FNR{\
        print gensub(/[ \t]+/, b, 1)\
      }' file1 file1
```

Note that you have to provide `file1` twice.

Output:

```
firstCol                    secondCol
blablablablablaetcetc                    secondCol
test123                    12231blablablabla
test123                    againtest123testbla
blablatest                    againblabla
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first column always starts on the first character and there are no spaces at the end of the second column:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){c=length - length($1) - length($2); if(c>m) m=c; next}
     (FNR==1) { s=sprintf("%*.s",m,"") }
     { print $1 s $2 }' file file
```